# jQuery how to call a method within a prototype?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery:

```
    function Morphing( button, container, content) {
    this.button = button;
    this.container = container;
    this.content = content;
    this.overlay = $('div.overlay');
}

Morphing.prototype.startMorph = function() {
    this.button.on('click', function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(200);
        Morphing.containerMove();
        // Work on from here!
        // setTimeout(Morphing.containerMove, 200);
    });
};

Morphing.prototype.containerMove = function() {
    console.log(this);
    this.overlay.fadeIn();
    this.container.addClass('active');

    this.container.animate(Morphing.endPosition, 400, function() {
            this.content.fadeIn();
            this.span.fadeIn();
            Morphing.close();
    });
};
```

Im trying to run the containerMove function when the button is clicked, but instead, I receive the error:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Morphing.containerMove()')
    (anonymous function) (newScript.js, line 11)
    dispatch (jquery.min.js, line 3)
    i (jquery.min.js, line 3)
```

This is the only error. I presume that it's because I'm calling the method incorrectly? Thanks.

On a side note: Is writing methods within prototypes like I have done a good practise?

Extra code:

Forgot to mention, this is in my index.html :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var morph = new Morphing( $('button.morphButton'), $('div.morphContainer'), $('h1.content, p.content') );

    morph.startMorph();

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to store the original `this` in a closure

```
Morphing.prototype.startMorph = function() {
    var me = this;
    this.button.on('click', function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(200);
        me.containerMove();
        // Now for the set timeout, you'll want to make sure it's
        // called with the corect `this`, You can use Function.bind
        // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
        setTimeout(me.containerMove.bind(me), 200);
    });
};
```

In your event handler, `this` points to the element itself, as you seem to understand from the fact that you call `$(this).fadeOut(200);` but you need access what `this` was outside of the handler.

Comment: That works great! Thanks. Just a question: why doesn't Morphing.containerMove() work? Surely if this = Morphing than it should?

Comment: @George because Morphing would need to be instantiated (created with the `new` operator, for you to be able to call it that way.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS `me` is also commonly used, edits should not be for your own stylistic preferences

Comment: @George `Morphing.containerMove` would only work if you defined the method on the constructor itself (think static method, e.g., Morphing.containerMove = function() {....}) instead of the prototype (think instance method)

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I have edited in a little other question which Im also having trouble with, thanks!!

Comment: @George At Stack Overflow, each post should be for a single question. That way, posts are more useful to others. Please accept this answer and post a new question.

Comment: Sorry, will do. It's just I have to wait 90 minutes to post another question (stupid in my opinion). I want to code now! Thanks again

Comment: @George Bummer... Those restrictions will go away once you have a little more rep